# Why does `grep` seem to give slightly different results with a plain `ls` command?

Tags: bash, grep, ls

I have a directory with some files -

```
mkdir _tmpmm
touch a1 b2 c3 d4
ls
# a1  b2  c3  d4
```

When I grep for *a* on the output of `ls`, I see only the file *a1* - although the `ls` output is showing 4 files on **the same line**

```
ls | grep a
# a1
```

However, if I create a file named "file_with_names.txt" containing the following lines -

```
cat file_with_names.txt
# a1 b2 c3 d4
# xxx
# zaz
```

And then do either

`grep a file_with_names.txt`

OR

`cat file_with_names.txt | grep a`

I get -

```
# a1 b2 c3 d4
# zaz
```

So, my question is - why does grepping for *a* on the `ls` output not return the full line - i.e. `a1 b2 c3 d4`?

Comment: also, [don't try to parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead); there's better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grep` command matches against the input it's given

Here, the input is the output from `ls` (bad practice, but let's ignore that for now), so the match is the single file name containing `a`:

```
ls | grep a
```

Here, the input is the output of `cat`, which in turn is the contents of the file `file_with_names.txt`:

```
cat file_with_names.txt | grep a
```

If you're asking why `grep` didn't match what you saw as the output from `ls`, which included four file names, that's because `ls` produces different output depending on whether it's writing to a terminal for a person to see it writing to a pipe for a subsequent program to see. Try this to see what gets output when it's writing to a pipe:

```
ls | cat
```

Generally, it's better not to try and parse the output from `ls`; there are usually better ways of getting a list of filenames

Comment: So, the single line output I see when I just do `ls` is because it has been optimized to display in the terminal while from the perspective of the `grep` that comes after a `|` - the output from `ls` contains newlines? Are there other commands with this kind of behaviour? I mean, different when output to a terminal vs a file?

Comment: Not very many. Some utilities such as `rm` and `mv` won't bother asking if you're sure about performing a dubious operation unless there's a terminal from which to receive an answer. The shell will act differently depending on how it's invoked